# Warning: Undefined array key in "searchref" and "searchapp" in php while connect with other website

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Let me explain my schenerio
I have a verification page in php code which is connected with Google spreed sheets database at main domain , and it's working Fine .
Now I want to seperate this page into Subdomain
When I live at Subdomain it's through Error
But actually it's working fine with main domain
Main Domain: https://rudnenclave.com/verification.php
Subdomain: https://verification.techno-holt.com/verification.php

at my subdomain its show error and at my old website its wokring fine
its same code

[image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Considering those keys reference form inputs, those keys will not exist until after the form is submitted. Make sure the form is submitted before you try to access those keys.

Answer (score -1):

For the 1 & 2 warnings:
You are trying to access "searchref" & "searchapp" array key which are not exists. So you could have a check with this function `isset()` to eliminate the warnings.

For the third warning: You have not defined the variable `$no_record` anywhere in your code. So define `$no_record` as an empty variable at the top and it should fix this issue.